# Is a form component with validation still presentational? Or should I make it a container?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form component which now receives an onSubmit handler via its props, so it is not attached to state directly.
Before calling onSubmit, the component validates itself and generates errors. Now I'm wondering if this component can still be considered presentational, since it's doing some 'smart' work in validating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about this too much. "Containers" is just a naming convention people use for react components that are usually "connected" to a store.

Keep your validation inside the same form component so everything regarding that form is encapsulated and nothing leaks outside of it. As you stated yourself, the component isn't connected to state directly. The parent component shouldn't care about validation, all it needs to know about is the returned value/object from the `onSubmit` handler.